# Urge/reason for inventing  interior product ( Grassmann algebra )

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, linear-algebra

Hello everyone,

I wanted to lecture on Grassmann and his works , and I have been reading the collected works of Grassmann " Die Lineale Ausdehnungslehre ". There Grassmann introduced something called " Interior product " ( Left and Right interior products ) . So I was completely stuck up there, the Bourbaki papers don't speak on the reason or urge in creating such manipulations, but its understood by someone who really mastered them.

Can anyone suggest me a good definition of the left and right interior products and explain the purpose of introducing them along with the intuition ?

I would be really honored to hear that.

Thank you.

Comment: Contrary to your claims, Bourbaki does explain the geometric meaning of interior products in a way that is accessible for somebody unfamiliar with the subject.  See sections III.11.12 and III.11.13 in Algebra (3rd edition).  In fact, Bourbaki is the only book known to me that explains the geometric meaning of interior products in exterior algebras.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov : I have edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: I still very strongly disagree with your characterization of Bourbaki's book.  The paragraphs I referred to are very easy to read and the geometric meaning behind them is crystal clear and stated very explicitly in the text.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov : I am not looking about the geometric meaning, but the need to introduce them.

Comment: Well, the geometric meaning also immediately explains why we should introduce them.  Orthogonal complements constantly pop up in all branches of mathematics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an elementary  motivation  for interior products .

Suppose $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space  .
To every non-zero vector $ v\in V$ you can associate the  complex $$ 0\to V\to...\to \Lambda ^kV\to \Lambda ^{k+1}V\to...\to  \Lambda ^nV\to 0 \\quad (\star)$$ 
where the linear map $ext_k(v):\Lambda ^kV\to \Lambda ^{k+1}V$ is the map  $\omega \mapsto v\wedge \omega$.
But how do you prove that it is exact? Answer: with interior products!

Choose a linear form $f\in V^*$ such that $f(v)=1$ and  introduce the interior product map  $int_k(f):\Lambda ^kV\to \Lambda ^{k-1}V$ which on a decomposable vector reduces to $$int_k(f)(v_1\wedge...\wedge v_k)=\sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{j+1}f(v_j)v_1\wedge...\wedge \widehat {v_j}\wedge v_k$$ 
It is then  easy to show the relation $$int_{k+1}(f)\circ     ext_k(v)+ext_{k-1}(v)\circ int_k(f)=Id_k: \Lambda ^k(V)\xrightarrow {=}   \Lambda ^k(V)      $$ 
which immediately implies that the complex $(\star)$ is exact at the $k$-th slot since   $$ext_k(v)(\omega)=0\implies \omega = ext_{k-1}(v)[int_{k-1}(f)(\omega)]    $$
 Differential geometers make  essentially the same calculation  in the context of the De Rham complex of differential forms: see Exercise 4 of Chapter 7 (Volume I) in Spivak's wonderful [*A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*](http://www.mathpop.com/bookhtms/dg1.htm)

**NB** The above  is the toy version of the theory of the Koszul complex.
It  can always be souped up to any desired degree of unintelligibility (in my case not much souping up is necessary) .

Comment: I think that the relation should be $\mathrm{int}_{k+1}(f) \circ \mathrm{ext}_{k}(v) + \mathrm{ext}_{k-1}(v) \circ \mathrm{int}_{k}(f) = f(v) \mathrm{id}$.  Note the similarity to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68378/clifford-algebra-non-zero/  These are the operators used to define the representation of the Clifford algebra of $V \oplus V^*$ (with symmetric bilinear form coming from the dual pairing) on the exterior algebra $\Lambda(V)$.

Comment: Dear @MTS: well, yes, but that is exactly why in line 7 I chose $f(v)=1$, so that my equality is correct, and yours too ! Anyway, thanks for the link

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that you chose $f(v) = 1$.  My bad.

Comment: This becomes an utmostly natural thing to do if one factorizes the complex $\Lambda V$ as the tensor product $\Lambda(v)\oplus\Lambda V'$ with $(v)$ the subspace spanned by $v$ and $V'$ a complement of $(v)$ in $V$. Standard general nonsense implies one need only show one of the two factors is exact, and dealing with $\Lambda(v)$ is immediate. Translating that standard general nonsense back to the complex $\Lambda V$ gives interior products.

Comment: (Urgh: the $\oplus$ should be $\otimes$)

Comment: ALthough I agree with all of this, isn't $int_k(v): \Lambda^{k+1}V^* \rightarrow \Lambda^kV^*$ just the naturally defined transpose of $ext_k(v): \Lambda^kV \rightarrow \Lambda^{k+1}V$?

Comment: Your nota bene is quite on the mark: the Kozszul complex is one of those very simple things than can be complicated into being as inintelligible as one can imagine :-)


Comment: Good answer ! , +1 . But a small query, Did Grassmann introduced them for the same purpose you mentioned or its an application that is digged out by the people later ? 

Comment: Dear Shanmukha, I'm afraid I don't know: I haven't read  Grassmann's original work. I only know that his contemporaries were very puzzled by his apparently unmotivated research, a common phenomenon with very original thinkers. 

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think that Hodge theory and differential forms are in air at the time of Grassmann. I am very much keen in listening to the application or the idea that forced Grassmann to introduce these interior products. May be there is some application to the "Parallelogram" or some universe related theories where we consider the motion of the planets and the vector theories underlying them. What do you say ? 

Comment: But I am not clear about the application. I would be really happy if someone explicitly specify the need of introducing them using the authentic references. 

Answer (score 9):

Grassmann's original motivations came from mechanics and geometry. Here is what he wrote in the foreword to his 1844 book "Die Lineale Ausdehnungslehre, ein neuer Zweig der Mathematik (Linear Extension Theory, a new branch of mathematics)":

"While I was pursuing the concept of product in geometry as it had been established by my father, I concluded that not only rectangles but also parallelograms in general may be regarded as products of an adjacent pair of their sides, provided one again interprets the product, not as the product of their lengths, but as that of the two displacements with their directions taken into account. When I combined this concept of the product with that previously established for the sum, the most striking harmony resulted; thus whether I multiplied the sum (in the sense just given) of two displacements by a third displacement lying in the same plane, or the individual terms by the same displacement and added the products with due regard for their positive and negative values, the same result obtained, and must always obtain."

More can be found at http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Extras/Grassmann_1844.html

There is a very accessible account in the  talk "Grassmann, Geometry and mechanics" by John Browne:

https://sites.google.com/site/grassmannalgebra/hermanngrassmann

Comment: +1. Thank you for your information.

Comment: Well, Margaret, your answer exactly described that for which I was waiting. But the above answer gives a practical application and motivation, so I had to choose it, Sorry. But on the other hand I thank your efforts for answering with great references, that are quite useful.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.